# Italicize one word and not others in draw.io

Tags: formatting, app.diagrams.net

I am using draw.io to make diagrams related to genetics. It is convention in my field to italicize gene names.

I would like to have a box that says "*genename*::cDNA" where "genename" is italic and "cDNA" is not.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

A bit late now, and maybe obvious, but draw.io now supports the "Formatted Text" Text option which allows you to apply bold, italics, etc to any text block or sub-regions of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, we need to make it more accessible, though.

Open up the UML library on the right and drop in, say, the interface object. Double click to edit, remove the content, then add yours.

This object is actual HTML, so you can apply formatting to individual parts. The standard label doesn't have this functionality. We might consider defaulting all labels to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods work:

- remove text and paste the formatted one (formatted using another tool): OR
- set the checkbox "Formatter Text" on the format panel → tab "text"